# Alternative ways to find $ \lim_{x\to 1}\; \frac{1-x}{1- \sqrt{x}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Searching on Google by a solution, I found this:

$1) \space$The numerator can be written by a difference of squares:$\space (1-\sqrt{x})(1+\sqrt{x})$

$2 \space)$Then, one can "eliminated" the common factor between the numerator and the denominator.

$3) \space$The final expression looks like:
$$ \lim_{x\to 1}\; {1+ \sqrt{x}}=2$$

However this was not a intuitive algebraic solution. I haven't thought of this solution at the first attempts. Could you please give me other alternative algebraic solutions, if it exists. Thanks.

Comment: Same solution, let $x=u^2$, but now instantly familiar.

Comment: Why isn't it intuitive? If you have a $0/0$ form, the first thing one usually does is search for common factors.

Comment: The difference of two squares method was the first thing that popped into my head before I clicked the link to this question!

Comment: The other approach to this solution is to think - that was neat, how will I be able to spot neat solutions like that next time and the comment from @AndréNicolas was exactly what I was going to put.

Comment: A slight variation.  Seeing $1 - \sqrt{x}$ you should want to multiply it by $1 + \sqrt{x}$ as a first instinct, so in this case multiply by $$\frac{1+\sqrt{x}}{1+\sqrt{x}}.$$

Comment: WimC, if I multiply as you said, I still get a indeterminated form $(0/0)$.

Comment: @João What's $(1-\sqrt{x})(1+\sqrt{x})$?

Comment: David Mitra, you are right, but I wasn't seeing how to find the commum factor

Comment: I am not sure but i think in most texts the precedence of the $\lim$ is higher than that of $+$. so I would write $$ \lim_{x\to 1}\; ({1+ \sqrt{x}})$$ instead of $$\lim_{x\to 1}\; {1+ \sqrt{x}}$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can compute the inverse: $$\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{1-\sqrt{x}}{1-x}=\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{\sqrt{x}-1}{x-1}$$ which is, by definition, $f'(1)$ where $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$.

Comment: As I understood, you "turn over" the fraction,by puting $\frac{1-\sqrt{x}}{1-x}$ on the denominator. Then you multiplied the denominator by $\frac{-1}{-1}$ to get the final expression, that is under the main fraction (the numerator is $1$).Finally you computed the derivative of $\sqrt{x}$ at $x=1$ to get $\frac{1}{\frac{1}{2}}$. Is that?

Comment: Yeah, that's basically it. Essentially, if $g(x)/h(x)\to A$ then $h(x)/g(x)\to 1/A$

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps we can use L'Hospital rule here ?

Answer (score 2):

Same solution, let $x=u^2$, but now instantly familiar.

Answer (score 1):

By substitution:$\quad$ let $x = u^2\,.\quad $Then as $x\to 1,\;\;u^2\to 1\implies u\to 1$, giving us $$ \lim_{x\to 1}\; \frac{1-x}{1- \sqrt{x}} \;\;=\;\; \lim_{u\to 1}\; \frac{1-u^2}{1- u} = \lim_{x\to 1} \frac{u^2 - 1}{u-1} \;=\;\lim_{u \to 1} \frac{(u-1)(u+1)}{u-1} = \lim_{u\to 1}(u + 1)  = 2$$

Using the substitution makes the "difference of squares" route looks so much more obvious!

Comment: If $u^2 \to 1$, then $u \to 1$ or $u \to -1$. Is this second situation if one compute the limit we get $0$.M'I rigth?

Comment: since $x \to 1$, the only root of concern is u = 1 (since $u = \sqrt{x}$ must necessarily be $\ge 0$ in this situation.